# Automatically adding data from other model

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewbag

I have models Workplace.cs and Request.cs

```
public class Workplace
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Cartridge { get; set; } = "";
    }

 public class Request
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Workplace { get; set; } = ""; (person can choose Name from Workplace here, I did it)
        public string Cartridge { get; set; } = ""; (the same value is required like Cartridge in Workplace)
        public string Comment{ get; set; } = "";
    }
```

I did in request form with help of ViewBag that user can choose number of workplace (Name). How can I realise automatical addition of value "Cartridge" from workplace?

Comment: If I am not mistaking you want to get the value of the Cartridge, populated based on the choice of the Workplace in the HTML?

Comment: @AchoVasilev yes

Comment: You will need JavaScript or JQuery for that.